# Wrap text in seaborn barplot x-axis python

Tags: python, label, data-visualization, customization, seaborn

I'm trying to plot a dataframe and I want the x-axis labels to not override each other like here

[image]

When dealing with one plot, adding `.set_xticklabels(rotation=30)` does solve the issue:

```
sns.catplot("foo", data=boo, aspect=5, kind="count" ).set_xticklabels(rotation=30)
```

[image]

but when I add the `ax` argument as here:

```
sns.catplot("foo", data=boo, aspect=5, kind="count" , ax=fig.add_subplot(211) ),
```

it doesn't (see the first snapshot).

I tried `sns.catplot("foo", data=boo, aspect=5, kind="count", ax=ax1).set_xticklabels(rotation=30)`

I'm looking for some kind of excel's "wrap text". I tried looking in seaborn attributes and had no success. I also tried to make the x-axis values smaller, but it was still overriding each over in some of the labels.

Comment: See some solutions here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540035/rotate-label-text-in-seaborn-factorplot

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540035/rotate-label-text-in-seaborn-factorplot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rotate label text in seaborn factorplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540035/rotate-label-text-in-seaborn-factorplot)

Comment: You can manually rename your categories so that they have the new line character. This might not be the most elegant/automated solution, but it get's things done.

Comment: See a solution that worked for me on medium here: https://medium.com/dunder-data/automatically-wrap-graph-labels-in-matplotlib-and-seaborn-a48740bc9ce

Answer (score 0):

Disc - This is my first post on 'StackOF'. Please excuse me if it is not up to your expectations. To wrap the x-axis labels in Seaborn is not possible (afaik) but even with Dexplot there are too many limitations. Here is the logic for achieving this using Matplotlib (using python).

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

raw_data = {'plan_type':  ['this is big ticks number one', 'this is also a big ticks number two Group B', 'and this as well a very big ticks number three Group C', 'this is no exception than a very big ticks number four Group D','Group E'],
        'Total': [56,24,18,49,67],
        'Total_PY': [12,82,33,60,16]
}


df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, 
              columns = ['plan_type', 'Total', 'Total_PY'])


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14,9))
ax = df.plot.bar(rot=0, ax=ax, color=['#FF5733','#2323ff'], 
             width = 0.7 )


for p in ax.patches[1:]:
h = p.get_height()
x = p.get_x()+p.get_width()/2.
if h != 0 :
    ax.annotate("%g" % p.get_height(), xy=(x,h), xytext=(0,4), rotation=0, 
               textcoords="offset points", ha="center", va="bottom")


ax.set_xlim(-0.5, None)
ax.set_ylim(-0.5, 120)
ax.margins(y=0)

ax.legend(ncol = len(df.columns), loc="lower right", bbox_to_anchor=(0,1.02,1,0.08), 
          borderaxespad=0, title= 'Year' )


ax = plt.gca();
labels = df["plan_type"].tolist()
new_labels = []

for tick in labels:
word_list = tick.split();
new_labels.append(word_list);


new_ticks = []
for label_tick in new_labels:

if(len(label_tick) >= 2):

    joined = ' \n'.join(label_tick);
    new_ticks.append(joined) ;
else:
    joined = ' '.join(label_tick);
    new_ticks.append(joined) ;

plt.xticks(ticks = df.index, labels = new_ticks)
plt.xlabel('Type of Plan')
plt.ylabel('Count of Numbers')
```

Answer (score -2):

This isn't possible with seaborn, but it is with [dexplot](https://dexplo.org/dexplot), a library similar to seaborn, but with many more features.

Below, is a bar chart with long labels. They are automatically wrapped, but can be wrapped at a specific position with `x_textwrap` and `y_textwrap`.

[image]

In seaborn, this same plot looks like this:

[image]